# How to find tangent vector

Tags: geometry

I'm looking at some notes in CAGD and there is written that for the curves:

> $f(u) = (-1 + u^2, 2u - u^2, 0)$
>
> $g(v) = (2v - v^2, 1 - v^2, 0)$ $u, v$ are in the interval $[0,1]$

the tangent vector is $(2, 0, 0$).

The problem is that I have no idea how it is found. Can you please tell me how to find it, or point me some kind of resource where I can read the algorithm?

Thank you very much in advance! :)

Comment: A tangent vector is typically found at a specified point (or a specified value of $u$ or $v$). Did they not give some kind of information like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tangent vector of a curve is just its derivative in the given point.
So, now it might be $f'(u)$ for some $u$ or $g'(v)$ for some $v$. Differentiation is done coordinatewise.